# Advection-Diffusion Equation with two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, tridiagonal-matrices

Consider the following equation:

$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \kappa \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} -u \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} -T \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

where $T$ is the temperature, $u$ is velocity and $\kappa$ is constant.
Converting this by finite difference method, for example Crank-Nicolson we get:

$(-\frac{u \Delta t}{4 \Delta x}-\frac{\kappa \Delta t}{\Delta x^2})T^{j+1}_{i-1}
+(1+2\frac{\kappa \Delta t}{\Delta x^2}) T^{j+1}_{i} 
+(\frac{u \Delta t}{4 \Delta x}-\frac{\kappa \Delta t}{\Delta x^2})T^{j+1}_{i+1} 
+T \frac{\Delta t}{4 \Delta x} u^{j+1}_{i+1} 
+ T \frac{\Delta t}{4\Delta x} u^{j+1}_{i-1} 
= 
(\frac{u \Delta t}{4 \Delta x}+\frac{\kappa \Delta t}{\Delta x^2})T^{j}_{i-1}
+(1-2\frac{\kappa \Delta t}{\Delta x^2}) T^{j}_{i} 
+ (-\frac{u \Delta t}{4 \Delta x}+\frac{\kappa \Delta t}{\Delta x^2})T^{j}_{i+1} 
+ T \frac{\Delta t}{4 \Delta x} u^{j}_{i+1} 
+ T \frac{\Delta t}{4\Delta x} u^{j}_{i-1}$

with $i$ representing space and $j$ representing time.
I am trying to determine how to numerically solve for both $T$ and $u$. I initially tried to do tridiagonal matrices and concatenate the matrices together but with no success.
Has anyone come across this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it will not be possible to solve for both $u$ and $T$ since you just have one PDE at hand. If you are given the velocity field $u$, you can solve for $T$ or vice-versa. But otherwise, your system is not closed.